# Setting the frame to a UIView not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation

I need a `UIView` to be hidden from the screen initially and then slides up. Kind of like a `UIActionSheetView` animation. In IB, I have set a `UIView` stick to the bottom border of the superview. In code, I have changed its frame to be hidden away from the screen when the app starts. And when it starts, the `UIView` slides up. Here's is my code. This **optionsSheetView** is the 'UIView' I'm referring to.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Hide the UIView from the screen initially
    self.optionsSheetView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.optionsSheetView.frame.origin.y + self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.height, self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.width, self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.height);

    // Sliding up animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.optionsSheetView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 374, self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.width, self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

Now here's my problem. This works just fine. But I don't like keeping hard coded values in my code. Like 374 for the optionsSheetView's `y` coordinate. If I put `self.optionsSheetView.frame.origin.y` there, it won't work. It's basically the same thing. When I replace it with its actual value which is 374, it works fine.

Why is this happening? Is there any way I can go about this without using magic numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: it's because optionSheetView y is already set to self.optionsSheetView.frame.origin.y + self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.height when you hid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CGFloat oldY = self.optionsSheetView.frame.origin.y;
    // Hide the UIView from the screen initially
    self.optionsSheetView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.optionsSheetView.frame.origin.y + self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.height, self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.width, self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.height);

    // Sliding up animation
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.9 delay:0.5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
        self.optionsSheetView.frame = CGRectMake(0, oldY, self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.width, self.optionsSheetView.frame.size.height);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```